# Add cells to beginning of collection view instead of end

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, infinite-scroll

I am including a form of infinite scrolling on my collection view, but the newest data is at the end of collection view and the old data is at the beginning. So when a user scrolls to the top of the currently loaded data, it loads in the next 5 cells (for this example). These five cells are loaded into the top 5 cells (because it is older data and oldest data is at top/beginning of collection view) which means the data on the screen shows these 5 newly loaded cells instead of the screen staying on the 6th cell (which was the first cell before the data loaded). **<- Since that doesn't make any sense, I have included pictures below**

[What screen looks like initially before loading in older data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlfZV.png)

[What screen looks like after loading in older data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKLT0.png)

However, I want the cell that contains "6" to still be at the top and have the previous cells above that so the user has to scroll for cells containing 1 - 5 to appear. Please ask any questions for clarification as this was hard to put into words

Comment: Do you have any code to share so that we can see what you've tried to do so far? It usually helps to guide you with a starting point like that.

Comment: I don't know where to start, I currently just have it working like a normal collection view where cells are added to end of collection view. When increasing the cell count, I just want to add cells to the beginning of the collection view instead of the end